# ES7 decorator doesn't work on class with "displayName" set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I'm adding React DnD to an app I'm building and have realised a ES7 decorator doesn't work (as far as I can tell) with the following syntax:

```
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
export class App extends React.Component {
    ...
}
App.displayName = 'My App'
```

Yet if I remove the `App.displayName` line everything is ok. Why?

How should I set the displayName property?

Comment: Does `displayName` have to be a property on the prototype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using ES7 features already, you can use ES7 [class properties](https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb). These are in stage 0.

```
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
export class App extends React.Component {
    static displayName = 'My App';
    //or just
    //displayName = 'My App';
}
```

If you're using babel, you'll need to enable the features using

```
babel --stage 0
```

or

```
babel --optional es7.classProperties
```

Comment: I think something was wrong with my setup as some => functions worked and others didn't. This is a good tip though. Thanks